# Sending streaming video to a server through node

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, video-streaming

I'm working on a small personal project (to learn node) and I'm wondering what the best way to send chunks of a video data from a client to the server is?  Obviously, I don't want to use Node's http module, but I've never used anything other than http.  I know there is a net module -- is this better?

Comment: If the client is going to connect to the server via plain TCP sockets, use the `net` module on the sides that you are going to use node.

Comment: by **client**, do you mean a browser?

Comment: Actually, I'm using an Android phone for my project, but the question applies to anything with socket connections (so I guess with Websockets and MediaCapture it could be done in the browser).

Comment: After researching this more on my own, I'm thinking the answer may be the real-time transport protocol (RTP) using UDP.  TCP trades speed for reliability, and that's not necessarily what I want with streaming.

Comment: @Nick, Are you looking for low-latency video?